# Как открыть доступ к ветке реестра HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT / *

Tags: windows, windows-10, реестр

Windows 10
Пытаюсь правой кнопкой мыши нажать и дать разрешения, пишет отказано в доступе.
Учётная запись - администратор.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Давай разрешения не на всю ветку, а на конкретный подраздел, в который нужно внести изменения (ПКМ - Разрешения). И сразу восстанавливай разрешения после выполнения нужных действий. Неправильные разрешения (в т.ч. избыточные) могут аукнуться... Если идёт отказ - проверь, кто владелец.

Comment: Я всё так и делаю, пытаюсь применить, а мне пишет "отказано в доступе" https://prnt.sc/ta96rr

Установить и поменять владельца не даёт.

Comment: *Установить и поменять владельца не даёт.* Значит, работает какая-то защита. Антивирус, например... *prnt.sc/ta96rr* Там есть кнопка "Дополнительно" - вот её и надо нажать.

Comment: Да, владельца тоже пробовал менял, вообще как будто наглухо всё заблокировано там https://prnt.sc/ta9kl9

Не даёт.

Антивирусов нету, чистая windows 10.

Comment: Возможно, на такой высокоуровневый узел есть запрет на смену доступа. Я например, с трудом понимаю, зачем на ВЕСЬ CLASSES_ROOT давать доступ.

Comment: Мне надо было поправить контекстное меню, а именно восстановить функцию "открыть с помощью".

Это исправляется в разделе реестра HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT / *

В общем переустановил просто винду, быстрее вышло :)

Comment: На что именно ты менял владельца? По скриншоту кажется, что ты ставил `*` в качестве имени пользователя. Попробуй написать `everyone` или `все` и потом нажать кнопку "Проверить имена".

Comment: Запустить regedit от пользователя SYSTEM.